# Pandas DataFrame Error: ValueError: StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA

Tags: python-3.x, string, types, int

Trying to convert kaggle titanic dataset pclass column datatype from int to string.
Using pandas 1.0.5.

```
df.Pclass.head()
0    3
1    1
2    3
3    1
4    3
Name: Pclass, dtype: int64
```

Code is below:

```
df['Pclass'] = df['Pclass'].astype('string')
```

Thrown error as below:

```
ValueError: StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA
```

Note: This worked for first time,not sure from 2nd time onwards keep getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

The below code worked. As pandas >= 1.0, they have suggested to use string instead of str. But if source is numeric then we can use str instead of string to work.

```
df['Pclass'] = df['Pclass'].astype('str')
```